# access view param in decorator, django

Tags: python, django, view, decorator

I have a simple view function, and a decorator for it, and I want to use a parameter passed to view in the decorator. I've googled around but haven't found any example for this, and I'm still not sure it this possible at all, and if so - how to do this?

View with decorator appended:

```
@user_is_project_maintainer
def edit(request, project_id_key):
```

decorator itself:

```
    def user_is_project_maintainer():
        def decorator(view_func):
            @wraps(view_func, assigned=available_attrs(view_func))
            def _wrapped_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
                if (project_id_key.isdigit()) :
                    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id_key)
                else :
                    project = get_object_or_404(Project, key=project_id_key)

                if (project.maintainer_id != request.user.id) :
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('core.views.index', args=(project.key,)))
                else :
                    view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

            return _wrapped_view
        return decorator
```

I've copied one of default django view decorators and amended it for my needs, I'm sure I've done it wrongly but it's not the case. The main thing I can't figure out - how to get my hands on the `project_id_key` var inside the decorator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In _wrapped_view you have access to args and kwargs. So project_id_key should be available as `args[0]`.
But I would rather do it in more explicit way:

```
def _wrapped_view(request, project_id_key, *args, **kwargs):
```

Answer (score 3):

It'll be in the `kwargs` in `_wrapped_view`, i.e. `project_id_key = kwargs['project_id_key']`.